# How to build a quaternary relationship in laravel 6?

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

I have to create a relationship between this tables:

[image: database schema]

As you can see, I need to relate 4 tables creating a quaternary relationship, asuming that the database model is ok, how i can do the relationship with eloquent?

In model **Subject**

```
public function curs_academic(){ // as academic year
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Curs_academic', 'assignatura_alumne_curs_professor', 'id_assignatura', 'id_curs_academic');
    }
    public function user(){ //as teacher
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'assignatura_alumne_curs_professor', 'id_assignatura', 'id_usuari');
    }
```

student is missing because i can't do even a ternary..

when i save i do this:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $this->validate($request,[
            'nom'=> 'required',
        ]);
        $assignatura = Assignatura::find($id);
        $assignatura->nom = $request->input('nom');
        $assignatura->save();
        $assignatura->estudi()->associate($request->estudis);
        $assignatura->curs_academic()->sync($request->curs_academic,false);
        $assignatura->user()->sync($request->professors,false);
        $assignatura->save();
        return redirect('/assignatures')->with('success','Assignatura modificada');

    }
```

pd: db model can change, I have tried to undo the Quaternary relationship, but without it it makes no sense (for me).

**Form inputs:**

```
<div class="form-group col-lg-6">
                      {!! Form::label('curs_academic', 'Curs academic') !!}
                      {!! Form::select('curs_academic[]', $cursos_academics, $assignatura->curs_academic()->pluck('curs_academics.id'), ['id' => 'curs_academic','multiple' => 'multiple', 'class' => 'selectpicker', 'data-live-search' => 'true']) !!}
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
                      {!! Form::label('professor', 'Professor') !!}
                      {!! Form::select('professors[]', $professors, $assignatura->user()->pluck('users.id'), ['id' => 'professors','multiple' => 'multiple', 'class' => 'selectpicker', 'data-live-search' => 'true']) !!}
                    </div>
```

Objective table:

**Subject** - **Student** - **year** - **Teacher**.
maths - ivan - 2019 - david. //
maths - ivan - 2018 - david.

Comment: What exactly is your problem here? I can't see any problem if you create separate models for each relation?

Comment: @Olivenbaum Well I dont rly know ho to sync the data, it is synchronized in chain, which creates duplicate values ​​in the database

Comment: What is the value of `$request->estudis` and `$request->curs_academic` and `$request->professors`?

Comment: All 3 are arrays of id. 
$request->estudis (mean subject) [1,2,3] -> 3 id of subjects, the same wiht the other ones. 
$request->curs_academic  (mean academic year)
$request->professors (mean teacher)

Comment: What is the content of the arrays? Please provide example input from your form.

Comment: I edit the question. @Olivenbaum

Answer (score 0):

You end up with duplicate entries because you use multiple relations for one table.

Try calling `sync()` only once with [pivot fields](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships).

This is because Laravel can't possibly know about another already existing record in your pivot table because it only looks for the key in the specific relation method.

A good approach would be to create an intermediate model for the pivot table und only use `BelongsTo` and `HasMany` relations. Then managing associations becomes pretty straightforward.

Comment: what do you mean? create a intermediate model for each class? or create a model for the pivot table? I'm sorry its my first laravel project..

Comment: Create a model for the pivot table. Then you can update all other relations with `associate()` and don't have to deal with complicated pivot fields. As your pivot table already has an `id` column this should be no problem. Just think of the pivot table as another regular table with a normal model that has relations to your other tables.

Comment: But doing in this way, if i'm not wrong, the table that i add in the question, will not work, I mean, the year will work great, but the other once not. It will not act as a quaternary..